# Why is it closed as not a real question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable). It may be considered as vague since it's not clear whether OP wants to delete only a row from the visual presentation of a JTable or from the underlying model layers too. But the current form of the question is the exact form of the question that is likely [to be Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=jtable%20remove%20row). Of course, there are similar variants of the question. But they have fewer views.

Why is it closed as not a real question?

Comment: Because it's not a real question but a help vampire luring people for feeding. As you can see from the OP's comments to the answers there, he is just asking more questions and if the victim is foolish enough to follow through for long enough, then whoopsie-doo they have built his entire application for him.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning IMO that the only downside to being closed is that it can no longer receive any more answers. But there seem to be several answers already that are sufficient. So really there would be little to gain by allowing more answers on it.

Comment: "gimme teh codez" = insta-close

Answer (score 14, accepted):

More than likely because this reads as a request for code rather than an actual question. We ideally like to see some effort on behalf of the OP. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is the practical problem you face? The fact that you don't have the code to solve your problem does not count as a real question.

If you go to the ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page, you will find the entry "Do your homework".

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your
>   question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
>   and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
>   the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
>   answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant
>   answer!

It seems the OP has put in no effort of his own. Or at the very least this is not mentioned. Questions like those tend to be closed as "not a real question" by now. Keep in mind that closure happened well after the question was initially asked. Stack Overflow has evolved significantly and what might have been perfectly fine before, might not be appropriate under current rules/guidelines.

**NOTE:**
I see now that you have updated this question to its current form after closure as "not a real question". While still not a good question after your revisions, you should really not be surprised about the closure of [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1117888/3).

Comment: But question in current form seems to be better. There are a lot of other not closed questions that don't show research effort

Comment: It looks better, but still is not a real question. I this case I think there was simply no saving it. But I applaud you for trying. That's a very positive thing to do. If you see other such bad questions not being closed, they probably just fell through the gaps. We try our best to keep things clean, but we might miss some. That (perhaps unfortunately) does not imply that "your" question shouldn't be closed either.

Comment: @Andrey: Other, similar questions that haven't been closed is not evidence that this particular question also shouldn't have been closed, but rather evidence that those other questions probably should be closed.